# Knockout js to disable past date from the selected date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

Html code to bind the knockout model

```
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: responseUserSetUpData().userListViewModel">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"  data-bind="datePicker: ko.observable(new Date(FormatStartDate)) , textInput : FormatStartDate , attr: {id: UserId}, datePickerOptions: {startDate: new Date()}"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" data-bind="datePicker: ko.observable(new Date(FormatEndDate)), textInput: FormatEndDate , attr :{id: UserId}, datePickerOptions: {startDate: new Date(FormatStartDate)}" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Knockout Js custome Binding for date picker

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                var unwrap = ko.utils.unwrapObservable;
                var dataSource = valueAccessor();
                var binding = allBindingsAccessor();
                var options = {
                    keyboardNavigation: true,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true,
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    startDate: userManagementVM.StartMeetingDate()
                };
                if (binding.datePickerOptions) {
                    options = $.extend(options, binding.datePickerOptions);
                }
                $(element).datepicker(options);
                $(element).datepicker('update', dataSource());
                $(element).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    if ($(element).is(':focus')) {
                        $(element).one('blur', function (ev) {
                            var dateVal = $(element).datepicker("getDate");
                            observable(dateVal);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        observable(ev.date);
                    }
                });
                //handle removing an element from the dom
                ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                    $(element).datepicker('remove');
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                $(element).datepicker('update', value);
            }
        };
```

Now, I want to disable all the past date in calender from the selected start date. It should disable all the past date from the selected date.

Here is the two property of the view model

```
StartMeetingDate: ko.observable(new Date()),
    EndMeetingDate: ko.observable(),
```

How can I disable all the past date in calender using knockout custome binding.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated answer that takes into account that low limit on `endDateLowLimit` should be set not only on startup but also should be updated dynamically each time `startMeetingDate` has changed

As I've said in a comment I don't believe that there is 'pure knockout' way to implement this dynamic behavior.

Though you can apply custom event fired each time `startMeetingDate` is changed and customize the `datePicker` binding to react on the event.

You View Model then may look like this:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self   = this;
    //    ..... 
    self.startDateLowLimit = ko.observable(new Date());
    self.startDateHihgLimit = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        return new Date(self.startDateLowLimit().getTime() + 30 * 86400000);    //  roughly 30 days from self.startMeetingDate()
    });

    self.startMeetingDate = ko.observable(self.startDateLowLimit());

    self.startMeetingDate.subscribe(function(newStartDate) { $('#endDate').trigger('DATE-FROM-CHANGED', [newStartDate])});    //    this is where custom event is fired


    self.endDateLowLimit = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        return self.startMeetingDate();
    });
    self.endMeetingDate = ko.observable(null);
    //    ..... 
}
```

The markup maybe like this:

```
<label>Start meeting date</label>
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"  id="startDate"  data-bind="datePicker: startMeetingDate, datePickerOptions: {startDate: startDateLowLimit(), endDate: startDateHihgLimit()}" >
<label>End meeting date</label>
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"  id="endDate"  data-bind="datePicker: endMeetingDate, datePickerOptions: {startDate: endDateLowLimit()}" >
```

Note that having `id="endDate"` attribute in second input is essential because `self.startMeetingDate.subscribe` handler uses this id to target the event.

Also note using `datePickerOptions` along with `datePicker` in the `data-bind`. We need it to set initial options of the `datepicker`.

And now to customizing the `datePicker` binding. Add this code that creates event handler into the binding's `init` method.

Just before this comment `//handle removing an element from the dom` would be a nice place.

```
$(element).on('DATE-FROM-CHANGED', function (ev, newStartDate) {
    const isDateValid = function(date) {
        //    this is a utility function that checks either parameter is a valid date
        return date.getTime && date.getTime() === date.getTime();    //    invalid date object returns NaN for getTime() and NaN is the only object not strictly equal to itself
    }

    var currentDate = $(ev.target).datepicker('getDate');
    if (isDateValid(newStartDate) && isDateValid(currentDate) && currentDate < newStartDate) {
        //    we should clean the current date if it is less then the new start date
        $(ev.target).datepicker('setDate', null);
    }
    $(ev.target).datepicker('setStartDate', newStartDate);    //    this is exactly where we set new start date for the datepicker
});
```

There still may be a full range of corner cases you'll have to cope with though I believe this answer helps you to get the general idea.

You may also find useful this documentation https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html in case you've missed it.

Below is a link to more elaborative (yet more hackerish) example that involves a range of date picker pairs placed on separate table rows. Note that knockout's `subscribe` is not involved in message passing in the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/rLh2r9pw/19/

Comment: How Do I disable the past date based on the user selected date in one Textbox. This solution works for initial loading of the page. It wont disable the past date if the user changes the date in first text box.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I solve this issue ..... I, am stuck on this problem

Comment: I believe that there is no 'pure knockout' way to set `startDate` option of `datepicker` dynamically.
To do so you'll have to add some events magic. Yet it will require customizing the `datePicker` binding.
I'll update my previous answer in some minutes.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope it's more helpful now. All the code snippets there are tested. I haven't put the whole code not to muddle its essential parts.

Comment: How can I, perform this with dynamic id on each row of the table.

Comment: Sure what you need is absolutely doable. Yet I believed I gave you enough hints so you could sort out all the necessary details with applying a bit of creativity. In case it wasn’t enough I updated my answer once more by adding a link to more elaborative example that does exactly what you’re asking about. Yet mind please that StackOverflow is a place where people share their knowledge not doing other people’s work.

Comment: Yeah .. Thank you